# Flask Live-Stream Not working with host attribute

Tags: python, opencv, flask, web

I want to classify a video using opencv methods by using flask, the video to be classified is live-stream that is from the user.

I googled a lot, then finally I found some code and did this:-

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import time
import io
from PIL import Image
import base64,cv2
import numpy as np
# import pyshine as ps
from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin
import imutils
# import dlib
from engineio.payload import Payload

# detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
# predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
Payload.max_decode_packets = 2048

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins='*' )
CORS(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


def readb64(base64_string):
    idx = base64_string.find('base64,')
    base64_string  = base64_string[idx+7:]

    sbuf = io.BytesIO()

    sbuf.write(base64.b64decode(base64_string, ' /'))
    pimg = Image.open(sbuf)


    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pimg), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

def moving_average(x):
    return np.mean(x)


@socketio.on('catch-frame')
def catch_frame(data):

    emit('response_back', data)


global fps,prev_recv_time,cnt,fps_array
fps=30
prev_recv_time = 0
cnt=0
fps_array=[0]

@socketio.on('image')
def image(data_image):
    global fps,cnt, prev_recv_time,fps_array
    recv_time = time.time()
    text  =  'FPS: '+str(fps)
    frame = (readb64(data_image))

    # frame = changeLipstick(frame,[255,0,0])
    # frame = ps.putBText(frame,text,text_offset_x=20,text_offset_y=30,vspace=20,hspace=10, font_scale=1.0,background_RGB=(10,20,222),text_RGB=(255,255,255))
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame,[cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY,40])[1]

    # base64 encode
    stringData = base64.b64encode(imgencode).decode('utf-8')
    b64_src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'
    stringData = b64_src + stringData

    # emit the frame back
    emit('response_back', stringData)

    fps = 1/(recv_time - prev_recv_time)
    fps_array.append(fps)
    fps = round(moving_average(np.array(fps_array)),1)
    prev_recv_time = recv_time
    #print(fps_array)
    cnt+=1
    if cnt==30:
        fps_array=[fps]
        cnt=0




def getMaskOfLips(img,points):
    """ This function will input the lips points and the image
        It will return the mask of lips region containing white pixels
    """
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)
    mask = cv2.fillPoly(mask,[points],(255,255,255))
    return mask


def changeLipstick(img,value):
    """ This funciton will take img image and lipstick color RGB
        Out the image with a changed lip color of the image
    """

    img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None,1,1)
    imgOriginal = img.copy()
    imgColorLips=imgOriginal
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector(imgGray)

    for face in faces:
        x1,y1 = face.left(),face.top()
        x2,y2 = face.right(),face.bottom()

        facial_landmarks = predictor(imgGray,face)
        points =[]
        for i in range(68):
            x = facial_landmarks.part(i).x
            y = facial_landmarks.part(i).y
            points.append([x,y])


        points = np.array(points)
        imgLips = getMaskOfLips(img,points[48:61])

        imgColorLips = np.zeros_like(imgLips)

        imgColorLips[:] =value[2],value[1],value[0]
        imgColorLips = cv2.bitwise_and(imgLips,imgColorLips)

        value = 1
        value=value//10
        if value%2==0:
            value+=1
        kernel_size = (6+value,6+value) # +1 is to avoid 0

        weight = 1
        weight = 0.4 + (weight)/400
        imgColorLips = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgColorLips,kernel_size,10)
        imgColorLips = cv2.addWeighted(imgOriginal,1,imgColorLips,weight,0)



    return imgColorLips
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,port=9990 ,debug=True)
```

This is in main.py of flask

In the templates folder I have made index.html with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <style>
        #video {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Firefox */

        }
    </style>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.0/socket.io.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
    <video autoplay playsinline id="videoElement"></video>
    <canvas id="canvas"  width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class = 'video'>
        <img id="photo"  width="400"  height="300">
        <h1>video</h1>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var socket = io.connect(window.location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            console.log("Connected...!", socket.connected)
        });


        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

        video.width = 400;
        video.height = 300;


        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(function (stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            })
            .catch(function (err0r) {

            });
        }

        const FPS = 6;
        setInterval(() => {
            width=video.width;
            height=video.height;
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width , height );
            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, width,height );
            socket.emit('image', data);
        }, 1000/FPS);

        socket.on('response_back', function(image){
                photo.setAttribute('src', image );

        });

    </script>


 </body>

</html>
```

The problem is: I need to make sure that it works on the user's device, so when I change socketio.run() and add host='0.0.0.0' It stops having access to my webcam
How can I solve this?

also I am unable to show back the video :(

The Error in Console

```
polling-xhr.js:264          GET http://localhost:9990/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N_GnQuZ 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

Comment: what is shown on chrome or your browser devolpertools ? is there an error ?

Comment: Yes, Its cannot GET socketiourl.. I am unable to solve this error, I think this is main cause

Comment: add engineio_logger=true to your socketio.run call and look where its stuck, and get sure that no firewall is blocking you, wich error excaclty do u get ?

Comment: It is showing Unexpected-Argument engineio

Comment: I have updated the error, in console

Comment: ok and what does show the sever when u get this error on js side ? did you see cors errors ? its just about debuging, when you set 0.0.0.0 you also need to update js side to real ip address of the host

Comment: see below my answer, update socketio and also check the securtiy context, otherwise you dont see the webcam on chromium based browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey,**

**First** you are using a very old socketio client version.

```
https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js
```

use a newer version of socketio client, thats the reason for 400 Error, if you are going to the preview window of the request on dev tools (chrome) you have notice that there are a not supported version message.
[image]

**Why you dont see the webcam!?** is because you have no security context, when you go away from localhost like 0.0.0.0 you need a security context on chrome based browser it means you need HTTPS otherwise *"navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia"* will return undefined.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716619/error-activating-microphone-in-google-chrome)